# Sealed class type safety for when statements - kotlin

Tags: kotlin

how can I get type safety on a `sealed class` `when` statement, when used within an rx stream?

ex:

```
private val handleDealOperation: (DealOperation) -> State.Change = {
            operation ->
            when (operation) {
                //how to enforce type safety? `DealOperation` is a sealed class
            }
        }
```

Trying to be typesafe in the context of an rx stream.

```
source.map(handleDealOperation)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `when` expression does give you type safety for sealed classes, but there seems to be an issue with it in this specific case of storing a lambda in a variable.

If you use a function instead, it will require you to have all branches, as expected:

```
private fun handleDealOperation(operation: DealOperation): State.Change =
        when (operation) {
            // this will show a warning on `when`
        }
```

In my testing, using lambdas on their own seems to work fine, they properly require you to be exhaustive with the branches of `when` and return the right type from them (try putting yours directly into the `map` call as an argument), but storing them in a variable somehow compiles even when it seems like it really shouldn't.

It looks like this isn't a `sealed class` issue, but rather an issue with the `when` expression in lambdas, when assigned to a variable. This following code, for example, compiles and crashes at runtime, regardless of what the argument of `when` is:

```
val doSomething: () -> Int = {
    when ("") { }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(doSomething())
}
```

The exception being:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

The lambda would usually not compile without having a last expression that returns an `Int` value, but it looks like it has trouble checking the return type of the `when` statement. However, assigning it to a local variable first, and then attempting to return it does give you the proper checks and errors, and this doesn't compile:

```
val doSomething: () -> Int = {
    val x = when("") {}
    x
}
```

So to get back to the original question, you could use this as a hack for now:

```
private val handleDealOperation: (DealOperation) -> State.Change = {
    operation ->
    val temp = when (operation) {

    }
    temp
}
```

If someone can properly file a bug for this or explain the behavior, please do so.